# French cartoon series where a lava monster fights a noseless, orange-haired guy with a broken sword

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

When I was 13 years old, I watched a show on YouTube that appeared to be a French cartoon, drawn in anime style.

The only things that I remember about it is there was a giant lava monster holding a hammer, and after he falls in the water he turns into a tentacled cyclops thing. He ends up fighting a noseless guy with orange hair & a broken sword.

Also, they end their fight by jumping into an portal from other dimension, and the show name starts with something like "W".

Comment: When were you 13 years old? Or rather, when would this show seem to have been produced?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hey, I noticed you were online to provide an answer to a question. Have you checked your own question to see if there's an answer worth accepting?

Comment: @Dudu Munhoz - If my answer below is correct, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if it's incorrect, please indicate that with a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're describing the fight between [Goultard](https://wakfu.fandom.com/wiki/Master_Goultard) and [Rushu](https://wakfu.fandom.com/wiki/Rushu), from *[Wakfu: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakfu_(TV_series))*, a cartoon which originally aired in France from 2008-2010.

Goultard is a noseless, oranged-haired guy with a broken sword, as you described, and Rushu has two forms, originally appearing as a hammer-wielding fire demon, and subsequently transforming into a tentacled cyclops.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.